# How to negate $\forall\epsilon > 0,\; \exists n_0=n_0(\epsilon)\in \Bbb{N},\ni |a_n-a^{*}| <\epsilon,\;\;n\geq n_0$

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

This became somewhat a concern to me today, when asked to *negate* the following definition of convergence below;

> $$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=a^{*},\;\text{i.e.},$$
>
> $$\forall\; \epsilon > 0,\; \exists\;n_0=n_0(\epsilon)\in \Bbb{N},\;\ni |a_n-a^{*}| <\epsilon,\;\;n\geq n_0$$

Please, can anyone show me how to negate the above definition?

Comment: Better use uniform notation for quantification, such as $$\forall \epsilon>0,\exists n_0\in\Bbb N, \forall n\ge n_0,\ni |a_n-a^*|<\epsilon$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Negation "percolates" from outside to inside by changing all quantifiers (even the bounded quantifiers used here):
$$ \begin{matrix}\neg&\forall \epsilon>0,&&\exists n_0\in\Bbb N,&& \forall n\ge n_0,&\ni&& |a_n-a^*|<\epsilon\\
& \exists \epsilon>0,&\neg&\exists n_0\in\Bbb N,&& \forall n\ge n_0,&\ni&& |a_n-a^*|<\epsilon\\
 &\exists \epsilon>0,&&\forall n_0\in\Bbb N,& \neg&\forall n\ge n_0,&\ni&& |a_n-a^*|<\epsilon\\
 &\exists \epsilon>0,&&\forall n_0\in\Bbb N, &&\exists n\ge n_0,&\ni& \neg&|a_n-a^*|<\epsilon\\
 &\exists \epsilon>0,&&\forall n_0\in\Bbb N, &&\exists n\ge n_0,&\ni&& |a_n-a^*|\ge \epsilon\end{matrix}$$

Comment: Excellent, explanation & answer all in one. I'd suggest you include your good comment below the question, as well, at the start of this answer.  But your answer doesn't require it.

Comment: @ Hagen von Eitzen: Thanks! This looks good to me!

Answer (score -1):

The negation is

$\exists \varepsilon >0~~\forall n_0\in\mathbb{N} ~~\exists n\ge n_0: |a_n-a^*|\ge\varepsilon$